# How do I turn edittext on and off?

Tags: android

I have an EditText field that has this

```
android:inputType="time"
```

I want to enable it with a button press (like change time) and disable it when done with another button press (like Enter).  Someone suggested that you can disable an EditText field with

```
textView02.setInputType(null);
```

Which works, but I can't figure out how to get it back to having the default method enabled.

The other thing I tried, and it comes close to working is to turn off the field with this

```
textView02.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

And turn it back on with this

```
textView02.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME);
```

But I get the full keyboard requiring shifting to symbols to get the :

I thought I could use this

```
textView02.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
```

but I get unwanted characters / and - and worse than that it takes a long press on my phone to get the : instead of the /

PS.  In a perfect world I would not need the enter function but instead rely on the done key on the pop-up keyboard.  But I can live with a dedicated button.

Allen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textView02.setEnabled(false);
```

And to reenable, pass it true.

Comment: Either of the two answers would have given me the solution so I thank both Tim and blackbelt. I picked this as the best answer because it included the code and a clear explanation of exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Every class extending `View` has the `setEnabled(boolean)` method.